# NODE & ELECTRON No valid versions available for electron-navigation

Tags: javascript

i tried to build a open source "Browser that allow flash player"
My problem is, when i use "npm install"
it's return me this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for electron-navigation

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rstei\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-18T13_30_37_799Z-debug.log
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Misaki",
  "productName": "Flash Browser",
  "description": "Electron Browser For Games",
  "homepage": "https://www.flashbrw.com",
  "author": "Misaki",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "publish": "electron-builder --win -p always",
    "build": "electron-builder --win"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.0.5",
    "electron-builder": "22.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-navigation": "^1.5.8",
    "electron-updater": "4.3.5"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.flashbrw.app",
    "extraResources": [
      "./plugins/**"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    },
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "asteroid-dev",
        "repo": "FlashBrowser"
      }
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "icon.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Flash Browser",
      "oneClick": true,
      "perMachine": false,
      "artifactName": "FlashBrowser.${ext}"
    }
  }
}
```

if you want see the open source: https://github.com/asteroid-dev/FlashBrowser
Thanks in advance for someone can find a way for fix it !

Answer (score 0):

Your project specifies a non-existent version of the `electron-navigation` module.

Your package.json calls for `"electron-navigation": "^1.5.8"`. The version specifier, `^1.5.8`, permits any version greater than or equal to 1.5.8 and *below* 2.0.0.

However, it appears the only available version of that package is version 6.6.6. You can confirm this from the command line:

```sh
$ npm show electron-navigation versions
6.6.6
```

The specifier `^1.5.8` does not accept 6.6.6.

I can only guess why your project is asking for such a precise but non-existent version. Change the specifier to `^6.6.6`, and it should install fine.